# Android : XML buttons and programmatically created buttons have slightly different font weight (with same attributes)

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, fonts

I have an app with multiple buttons in a ScrollView, and I add more programmatically after the Activity start (custom user buttons).

All buttons have the same styles and attributes, but on screen the ones that are created programmatically have slightly bolder text.

I examined them in the layout inspector and they all have the same values for attributes like getTextSize (20), getTypefaceStyle (NORMAL), height, width, styles, ...

What could cause a different in boldness with the same values for those attributes?

Example of one XML Button :

```
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_autre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_selector2o"
            android:text="Bonbons"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            />
```

Example of one created Button :

```
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.buttons_container);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutparams.setMargins(0, px, 0, 0); // px calculated to be 20dp

        ContextThemeWrapper ndfContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.button_style_xml);
        Button addbutton = new Button(ndfContext);
        addbutton.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
        addbutton.setText("Bonbons");
        addbutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_selector2o);
        layout.addView(addbutton);
```

Content of button_style_xml :

```
<resources>
    <style name="ndftype_style" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_selector2o</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Result : [image: screenshot of app]

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case, I got an idea while writing the question, thanks Canary Effect.

Despite all buttons having the same style and no font assigned to them anywhere, it seems Android was attributing a different default font to both kinds. I'm not sure why this is the case.

Adding

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
```

on my programmatically created buttons solved the issue.
You might want to add it to your XML buttons too to be safe.

If you target API level < 16, running the following on all your buttons should work :

```
button.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
```